# compare matrix matlab 2

Tags: math, matlab, matrix

this is my second question about comparing two matrices.I tried to compare two matrixes, (3x3) and (4x6).Fallowing code works perfect, but if I want to replace matrix z with commented line,matlab doesn't like my code anymore:( Could you please show my mistake!
I will be greatfull,
mgm

```
clear
x=[0  4  8 ;3 2 5 ;2 1 5 ]';
y=[0 1.1 2 2.1 3.6 7.3;1 3 2.2 2 3 2.4 ;2 1 3.3 3.4 6.7 5.8;3 3.4 5 6.6 6.5 7.8]';
z=zeros(6,3);
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        for p=1:6
            for r=1:4
                if x(i,1)==y(p,1)
                    z(p,j)=x(i,j);
                elseif (x(i,1)<y(p,1))&&(y(p,1)<x(i+1,1))
            z(p,j)=(x(i,j)+x(i+1,j))./2;%(x(i,j)+x(i+1,j)+x(i,j+1)+x(i+1,j+1))./4
        end
    end
        end
    end
end
```

end

Comment: `??? Attempted to access x(1,4); index out of bounds because size(x)=[3,3].` I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but the error is pretty explicit. When `j` is 3, then `j+1` is 4 which is larger than the size of `x`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!Could you please tell me, how to solve this error? For example how can I put another value for j+1 or i+1. As you see I'm trying to understand matlab thinking mechanism and I am really inexperienced on it:(  @Simon

Comment: What does compare two matricies mean when they're different sizes?  Game over.  This makes no sense at all.  The entire idea is wrongheaded.

Comment: actually, I compare the first columns of two matrix. If the column elements of two matricies equal to eachother, my program choose the first row of first matrix and if one of the column elements of second matrix stays between to consecutive column elements of first matrix it calculate the mean value of two row elements of first matrix and  creates a new row. In fact,"compare" is not a good choice to define my problem:(Anyway, I couldn't find a better description:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you posted does NOT work perfect - you got just lucky with the combination of numbers you have choosen ;).

Just witch the comparison of the values in the elseif statement you posted and you will see that this code does not work as intended.

switch this line:

```
elseif (x(i,1)<y(p,1))&&(y(p,1)<x(i+1,1))
```

to:

```
elseif ((y(p,1)<x(i+1,1)&&x(i,1)<y(p,1)))
```

This is, because matlab evaluetes the first expression in the statement and if it is false, it doesn't check the second statement - Therefore you don't get an error since the first statemaent in your code for the last elements is false 8 < 7.3

The error you are getting is, because you try to access elements out of the index of the matrices.

You have a 3x3 matrix and try to acces the element (4,1) in the last run of your for-loop. The same problem with the y matrix.